# Querying lucene index with single characters, e.g persons initials

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, hibernate-search

I have a database of companies and people that I want to query using Lucene (via Hibernate Search). The search feature is implemented as an autocomplete-style lookup, where the web page will suggest matches as the user types.

Some of the companies and people are identified using initials e.g.

- G & H CIVIL ENGINEERING
- J G VAN DER MERWE

I want the user to start getting matches after typing a couple of letters, but progressively refining the search as they add more text (possibly including spaces). I'm querying a couple of different fields, e.g. name, trade name, ID numbers, phone numbers etc. using the single term, such that the user could type part of the name, ID number, trade name or cell number.

However, I'm having trouble setting up the index and query such that a term like `G & H` will match the document. Using a term like `CIVIL`, there will be a lot of matches. However the single characters with spaces in between aren't matching anything.

The test below fails on the last line. I'm unsure of the combination of analyzers, tokenizers, filters & queries I should be using.

```
@Test
public void testSearching() throws Exception {
    Analyzer analyzer = new ReusableAnalyzerBase() {
        @Override
        protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
            StandardTokenizer tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_36, reader);
            LowerCaseFilter lowerCaseFilter = new LowerCaseFilter(Version.LUCENE_36, tokenizer);
            NGramTokenFilter filter = new NGramTokenFilter(lowerCaseFilter, 3, 20);
            return new TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer, filter);
        }
    };
    Directory ramDirectory = new RAMDirectory();

    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_36, analyzer);
    IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter(ramDirectory, config);

    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new Field("id", "819", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    doc.add(new Field("particulars.registeredName", "G & H CIVIL ENGINEERING", Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

    w.addDocument(doc);
    w.close();

    // search
    int numberOfHits = 200;
    TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(numberOfHits, true);
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(IndexReader.open(ramDirectory));

    PhraseQuery q = new PhraseQuery();
    q.add(new Term("particulars.registeredName", "civil"));
    searcher.search(q, collector);
    ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
    assertThat(hits.length, greaterThan(0));

    PhraseQuery phraseQuery = new PhraseQuery();
    phraseQuery.add(new Term("particulars.registeredName", "g & h"));
    searcher.search(q, collector);
    hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
    assertThat(hits.length, greaterThan(0)); // this fails - no matches
```

I'm new to Lucene - any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your particular issue is probably related to the fact you're reusing the collector, which is stateful and designed for one-time use only. Using a new collector in you second query should do the trick.

**However**, please note that with Hibernate Search you're not supposed to touch Lucene internals much: Hibernate Search will automatically derive Lucene documents from your entities at indexing time, and build index readers and collectors as necessary when querying. I strongly encourage you to avoid using Lucene directly if you're still new to Lucene/Hibernate Search: Lucene is powerful, but not an easy tool to use.

That would mean using annotated (or programmatically mapped) entities instead of building a document manually. Please refer to [the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/), in particular the [section about entity mapping](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-mapping) and the [section about analysis](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#_analysis).

Also, when querying, you may use [the Hibernate Search DSL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-query-querydsl). It will probably be easier than building raw Lucene queries. And when your query has been built, you may also ask Hibernate Search to [retrieve the results](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#_retrieving_the_results) easily.